# SQL Server: stored procedure with several parameters

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures, parameters, exists

In the Stored procedure I would like change my code, for use it on other database.
DATA: is name of a database
I have other databases for example: DATA2 and DATA3. I need to replace DATA by parameter @LocalBase.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ['' + @localBase + ''].SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE NAME = @DestinationSchema)        
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SQL = N'USE DATA; EXEC(''CREATE SCHEMA '' + @DestinationSchema + '')'
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
        INSERT INTO dbo.TableLog SELECT @id, @SourceServer, @SourceSchema, 'GetAllTables', @DestinationSchema, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Schema ' + @DestinationSchema + ' created', 2
    END
```

Is it possible (correct) to do this?
`

```
@SQL=N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ['' + @localBase + ''].SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE NAME = @DestinationSchema)'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

    BEGIN
        SELECT @SQL = N'USE ['' + @localBase + '']; EXEC(''CREATE SCHEMA '' + @DestinationSchema + '''')'
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
           INSERT INTO dbo.TableLog SELECT @id, @SourceServer, @SourceSchema, 'GetAllTables', @DestinationSchema, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Schema ' + @DestinationSchema + ' created', 2
    END
```

`

I would like to call the stored procedure like that:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @SourceServer nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @localBase nvarchar(255)

SET @SourceServer = 'Serv1,10001'
SET @localBase = 'DATA1'

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[stor_proc_name] 
   @SourceServer,
   @localBase
```

Comment: Why are you creating schemas dynamically like this? This has a lot of red flags that there are some very serious design issues here. And when you start using dynamic sql you need to be careful that you don't get a visit from our old friend bobbly tables. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: This code is a part of the the stored procedure code. that copies the tables of a database server to another server.
The stored procedure runs for the DATA database. but I want to make it generic to apply it to other databases

Comment: Well that is kind of scary but look at where you have your variable @LocalBase. Since this is now part of dynamic sql string you will need ''' not ''. As coded you have a string literal in your string. You need to get in the habit of examining dynamic sql BEFORE you execute it. If you look at the string you would notice the syntax error pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Sean is correct regarding the risk of these type of constructs. Your current solution is vulnerable to SQL injection, and will need to be very careful if you continue with this path as you have nested dynamic SQL constructs.
CREATE SCHEMA is being constructed dynamically within dynamic SQL, which means that you would have to escape the schema name not once, but twice, once for the CREATE SCHEMA construct (where it is acting as an object name) and once for the top-level dynamic SQL construct (string) otherwise you have two levels of possible SQL injection.

The following example based on your statement will hopefully demonstrate what I mean:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @localBase sysname
DECLARE @DestinationSchema sysname
SET @localBase = 'a''b]c';
SET @DestinationSchema = 'a''b]c';
SELECT @SQL = N'USE ' + quotename(@localBase) + ';
    EXEC(''CREATE SCHEMA ' + replace(quotename(@DestinationSchema), '''', '''''') + ''')'
print @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Notice that while the “USE” statement can be properly escaped using quotename, for the CREATE SCHEMA construct I have to escape twice; first I escape the ( ] ) characters using quotename as the name for the CREATE SCHEMA construct is an object identifier, but I also need to escape the ( ’ ) characters as it is also being used as a string (for EXEC statement).
One possible recommendation to make this a little bit more manageable would be to create different modules for constructing the string that will be used as nested dynamic SQL. For example (using the same example as above:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [a].[f_construct_create_schema_statement]( @schema_name sysname)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @retval nvarchar(max);
    SELECT @retval = 'CREATE SCHEMA ' + quotename(@schema_name) + ';'
    return @retval;
END
```

And the previous script changes to the following (which makes it easier to read, and easier to find errors):

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @parameters nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @localBase sysname
DECLARE @DestinationSchema sysname
SET @localBase = 'a''b]c';
SET @DestinationSchema = 'a''b]c';
SELECT @SQL = N'USE ' + quotename(@localBase) + '; 
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
    SELECT @SQL = [a].[f_construct_create_schema_statement](@DestinationSchema);
    EXEC( @SQL )'
print  @SQL
set @parameters = '@DestinationSchema sysname'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @parameters, @DestinationSchema = @DestinationSchema
```

Using this dive-and-conquer approach, you still have to be very careful when using  dynamic SQL, avoiding it as much as possible and using parameterization whenever it is allowed, but at least you will not have to deal directly with complex nested-escaping sequences.

I hope this information helps.

-Raul Garcia

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try this method and will tell you if it works.
Slim